# Excel "Removed Records: Formula from" log file does not identify what was removed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I modified the range of a formula within the spreadsheet's sheet6.xml file using the regular expression change/replace feature of EditPlus, using this regular expression:

Find: `(SUM\(J.*:)(S)(.*\))`

Replace: `\1\N\31`

Which, for example, correctly changes occurrences of `SUM(J1024:S1024)` to `SUM(J1024:N1024)`, as the spreadsheet contains no data beyond column N.

I then delete `calcChain.xml` and zip everything up into a new XLSM file.  When I load the file in Excel I get a message box popping up stating that the file contains errors and that, if I click OK, Excel will attempt to repair the file.  After clicking OK Excel states:

Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.

Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet6.xml part

Click to view log file listing repairs:  (blah, blah blah) \error123720_01.xml.

The contents of error123720_01.xml are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error123720_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\mbmas_000\Directory Junctions\Documents - Local\Estate Accounting-2016-05-19.Mod2.xlsm'</summary>
    <removedRecords>
        <removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet6.xml part</removedRecord>
    </removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

So, as you can see, the "detail" file contains no detail at all and adds no more information than the original dialog box presented.

The spreadsheet itself, once opened and displayed by Excel, looks fine.  My modified formulas are there.  Everything looks good; however, this is a gigantic spreadsheet and who knows if there's some error lurking in there.

I'd really like to know what Excel did when performing this "repair."  Is this logged anywhere?  Is there a way to get Excel to log it if it's not being logged?  I did try extracting the XML from the "repaired" file and comparing it to the XML that my change produced, but this proved to be very challenging, as Excel also took the opportunity to replace many of the redundant formulas with shared formulas (`<f t="shared" ...>`), significantly altering the original XML and making a comparison very difficult.